Detect Material You (Monet Engine) color changes in flutter
I'm creating a flutter app using the dynamic_color library to enable material you colors. However, It doesn't seem to react to material_you color changes.
I tried using a StatefulWidgets with WidgetsBindingObserver and didChangePlatformBrightness, however, it doesn't get called when the material you color changes. I tried navigating some native apps but I can't understand in which part they update the material you color
